# To send Form data to the same page using classic ASP

Tags: forms

I want to send Form data to the same page using classic ASP.

Code:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
'Classic ASP:
Dim test
test = request.form("CtrlTest")
response.write "result = '" & test & "'<br>"
%>
<!-- alternative: <Form name="test" method="POST" target="_self" > -->
<Form name="test" method="POST" action="" >
    <a href>ClickThis</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="CtrlTest" value="ATest" />
</Form>
</body>
</html>
```

After clicking I had expected the result to be:

"result='ATest'

ClickThis"

But it is:

"result=' '

ClickThis"

How can I read the posted data?

Tested in localhost mode:
Chrome OK, 
IE11: Error 403.14.

---

This makes me wonder how the **POST**ing happens:

The POST data is sent to a server that passes the data on to the target Receiving ASP or PHP page.

When the Receiving page opens **first** time after the transmission the data is available for request.

If the Receiving page is the same as the Sending page (e.g. target =”_self”) the data is immediately available in the page (**if it is** an ASP or PHP page).

The next time the Receiving page opens the data is no longer available.

**Is this correct?**

And this  should work OK even if I am in **localhost** mode, and not reaching an actual server?

If the Request lines in the Receiving page lies in **a file that is #included** into the Receiving file – will it still work?

Answer (score 0):

Links do not submit forms. They just go to the URL in the `href` attribute.

To submit a form, use a submit button.

```
<button>Submit</button>
```

Comment: My mistake in the code:  I changed ```<a href>ClickThis</a>``` to ```<a href='javascript:document.test.submit()'> ClickThis </a>``` and it worked OK. Sorry!